# Combine two hard disks in lubuntu 13.10

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have two HDDs and want to combine them to one, one had Debian installed that is 51gb, and other one is ntfs with 30gb space. I want to combine the 20gb from debian HDD and want to to add to my 30 GB.

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149140/2-hard-drives-one-partition?rq=1) though this may not work since you are trying to combine NTFS and ext partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It technically is not combining the two hard drives but you could mount the two drives at various points in your directory tree, giving you easy access to the space on the two drives.

You can learn a bit about the general philosophy of the hierarchal file system used in all Unix and Linux systems, including Ubuntu [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93960/why-is-linuxs-filesystem-designed-as-a-single-directory-tree).

Without knowing more about your current setup and usage pattern, it is hard to give very specific advise. A common usage is to have a separate drive for your home directory (make sure you copy your current home directory contents to the new location before finalizing the result.

By editing the `/etc/fstab` file you can make the new setup mount automatically on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Search for creating logical volume by lvm in Terminal (Google it ) , which allow you to create

physical volumes (you can extend these volumes ) ,after create volume group , then you create

a logical volume so the Storage will be the sum of the 2 volumes `like raid 0 .`