# Install Ubuntu on second SSD on Asus eeepc 901

Tags: asus, ssd, eeepc

I have an Asus eeepc 901 which previously had Windows XP installed - I'd like to replace this with Ubuntu 14.04 now that XP is out of support.

The eeepc model that I have has two SSD drives - one 4GB and one 8GB. When I get go to install Ubuntu, it shows the 4GB drive as the first drive.

It shows the following devices:

/dev/sda 4034 MB
/dev/sdb 8069 MB

I've tried installing Ubuntu on the 4GB drive with the 8GB drive for /home and swap. But although it ran, it was crippled by lack of disk space.

I thought about installing /root on the 8GB drive, but I get a message saying that the partition cannot be outside the disk.

My question is, what would people recommend as options for installing Ubuntu on this configuration? And how do I do it using the graphical installer? I have no knowledge of linux installations, so please keep it simple for me. I just want a easy-to-use OS for my netbook computer to give it a few more years life.

If you're not familiar with the eeepc 901, the specs for it are here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_PC

Dom

Comment: Is this two pyhsical drives or is this (more likely) two partitions on a single drive? What do you get when choosing "someting else" on installation?

Comment: There are two physical SSDs - one 4GB and one 8GB. When I choose 'something else' (this is how I installed ubuntu the first time) it shows two devices: /dev/sda = 4034MB and /dev/sdb = 8069MB

Comment: You could try if you have more luck with LVM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149140/2-hard-drives-one-partition - but it's more a guess, haven't tried that on such small drives.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would you be willing to post an answer summarising this option? I'm assuming there is some way of telling the installer that this a logical 12GB volume and then installing Ubuntu on this. Also, are there any other options? Could I install Ubuntu on the 8GB drive, where there would be enough space, and boot into that? Again, if this is an option, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer my own question now.

The answer is that I chose the default option in the installer, and when it asked me which disk I wanted to install Ubuntu on, I chose the second, 8GB hard disk.

The PC boots fine into the second hard disk, and there is about 2GB free.

The first 4GB hard disk shows up under 'Devices', and I have formatted this so I can use it to store data on.

Answer (score 1):

Although the questioner answered their own question, the answer is less than ideal as the larger SSD is slower than the 4GiB (this is why they had the split - fast expensive 4GiB vs slower cheaper 8/12GiB SSD). I did this on the 4GiB/12GiB model. I got the OS running happily on the 4GiB SSD. I wrote about it. If anyone is still interested, it's here:

https://coosoft.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/installing-ubuntu-on-an-asus-eee-901-pc/

Tony.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Yes, I agree it would be ideal to get the OS running on the 4GB SSD. I'll see if I can follow the recommendations in your articale - thank you.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your very useful and detailed write-up. I found it very informative for achieving an optimal installation of 14.04 on an old EEEPC 901.

Comment: Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two partitions on one 12 GB ssd you should delete all partitions upon installing and install it over the whole ssd. If there (most likely) is a normal hdd inside your computer, this harddisk should be used to store the /home folder.

Comment: There are two physical SSD drives 4GB and 8GB. There is no HDD.

Comment: Okay, where is the user data stored? 12GB seems a little too less to really work with the pc for me.

Comment: The computer was designed so that Windows XP could be installed on the 4GB drive and the data stored on the 8GB drive. The computer also has a SD card reader, so there is the ability to store any amount of data on removable media.